# How to select unoccupied ranges between two numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Consider I am having below table:

```
Id   | Title        | Start   | End    
-----+--------------+---------+-----
1    | Group A      | 100     | 200
-----+--------------+---------+-----
2    | Group B      | 350     | 500
-----+--------------+---------+-----
3    | Group C      | 600     | 800
```

I want to get unoccupied ranges between 100 and 999.
my required final result would be:

```
Id   |  Start   | End    
-----+----------+-----
1    | 201      | 349
-----+----------+-----
2    | 501      | 599
-----+----------+-----
3    | 801      | 999
```

Comment: How you are determining end in your output?

Comment: does any row will contain the previous rows data? I mean, can the 4th row be **Group D, Start:450, End: 700**?

Comment: @mehmetx no it can't

Comment: You should not use a reserved word (`End`) as a column name ... (see: [Reserved Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189822(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN))

Answer (score 1):

You can use lead() window function to do so.

```
Select Id, [End]+1 as Start, coalesce((lead(start)over(order by id) -1),999) [End] 
from mytable
```

Since at the last row result of lead() will be null I have used coalesce() to make it 999.

Schema:

```
 create table mytable( Id   int, Title varchar(50),[Start] int ,    [End]    int);
 insert into mytable values(1,    'Group A', 100, 200);
 insert into mytable values(2,    'Group B', 350, 500);
 insert into mytable values(3,    'Group C', 600, 800);
```

Query:

```
 Select Id, [End]+1 as [Start], coalesce((lead([start])over(order by id) -1),999) [End] 
 from mytable
```

Output:

| Id | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 201 | 349 |
| 2 | 501 | 599 |
| 3 | 801 | 999 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=33e469e836aa7c7733f4a2f65192193a)*

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem.  If I make the following assumptions:

- All the values are between 100 and 999.
- The values have no overlaps.

Then you can handle this with `lead()` and `union all`:

```
select null, 100,  min(starti) - 1
from t
having min(starti) > 100
union all
select title, endi + 1, next_starti - 1
from (select lead(starti, 1, 1000) over (order by starti) as next_starti, t.*
      from t
     ) t
where next_starti >= endi + 1;
```

Note that the first subquery is for a condition not in your sample data, but where the first value starts after 100.

For the more general solution where you could have overlaps, the simplest method might be to general all possible values, remove the ones that exist, and then combine the adjacent values:

```
with n as (
     select 100 as n
     union all
     select n + 1
     from n
     where n < 999
    )
select min(n), max(n)
from (select n.*, row_number() over (order by n) as seqnum
      from n 
      where not exists (select 1 from t where n.n between t.starti and t.endi)
     ) tn
group by (n - seqnum)
order by min(n)
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=26015bbd8dae88688709f0736cf0926d) is a db<>fiddle.